# Change the Permalink on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I want to change the permalink of the post/category that I have to custom link.
I'll attach the screenshot below. Any idea on how I can change the Permalink to custom link. Currently, I am allowed to edit the vista-hotel. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Go to `Settings -> Permalinks -> Select Custom Structure` and you can define your own structure. Otherwise you can use a plugin which enables the URL Rewrite

Answer (score 0):

To change the way WordPress uses permalinks is quite a simple process.

1. Go to the Settings section of your WordPress dashboard
2. One the left side of the dashboard under the Settings control, you should see one for Permalinks. This is what you should click.
3. Select the method you want to use and click the Save Changes button.

The “Custom Structure” located in the permalink settings page allows you to set up a more detailed method to create addresses. For example, you could include author names or even the precise time for each new post. The tags you can use include:

1. %year%
2. %monthnum%
3. %day%
4. %hour%
5. %minute%
6. %second%
7. %post_id%
8. %postname%
9. %category%
10. %author%

To use these tags, select the Custom Structure radio button. After the domain’s address, enter in each tag you want to include with a / in between. Here is an example:

/%author%/%monthnum$/%day%/%year%/%postname%/

This would show the author’s name, the number of the month, the day, the current year and the name of the post. For instance, it could look like:

http://yourdomain.info/john_doe/12/25/2015/name-of-the-post.

Don't forget to 301 the old urls once you have updated the permalinks